# How does firestore generate auto doc ID offline?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

`getFirestore().collection("MyCollection").doc()` creates a document with auto generated ID instantly without await. The function description is as follows:

> Get a DocumentReference for a randomly-named document within this
> collection. An automatically-generated unique ID will be used as the
> document ID.

It specifically said **unique**. How does it guarantee the ID is unique offline? The combination is 1.39e42, chances are low but not low enough to say impossible. If the collection has 1 trillion documents or millions of documents per day for hundreds of years, the chance of getting a nonunique ID is pretty high. For enterprise-grade projects, I don't think the risk is acceptable.

It's not just one user. For millions of users out there, the chance of someone's project hit this problem is not low at all.

Comment: `chances are low but not low enough to say impossible.` What, in your opinion, would be low enough to say impossible?

Comment: @tkausl The point is they said unique, that means it has to be 0%. I can think of some way to do it. For example, use a hash function where all nanosecond timestamp before year 5000 lead to different results. If consecutive ID generation takes more than 1 nanosecond, then the ID will be unique untill year 5000. But can't find anything say they did this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Await is used for asynchronous operations. The generation of the ID is not an asynchronous operation, as it takes place on the client. So there is nothing you should wait for.

The collisions of IDs are incredibly unlikely and you can/should assume they'll be completely unique. That's what they were designed for. So you don't have to be concerned about it.

This built-in generator for unique IDs that Firestore uses when you call `add()` or `doc()` without passing any parameters, generates random and highly unpredictable document IDs, which prevents hitting certain hotspots in the backend infrastructure.

Comment: Hey Jeffrey. Can I help you with other information?